# how to yield different values for different calls with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

i am trying to use `and_yield` the same way that `and_return` works.  i want it to yield ONE value each time its called... however it yields TWICE each time its called.

this contrived example shows the issue

```
class Yielder
  @@blocks = []
  def self.yielder; end
  def self.blocks= b; @@blocks << b; end
  def self.blocks; @@blocks; end
end

describe Yielder do
  it 'should yield twice' do
    allow(Yielder).to receive(:yielder).and_yield(:foo).and_yield(:bar)

    2.times do
      Yielder.yielder do |y|
        Yielder.blocks = y
      end
    end

    expect(Yielder).to have_received(:yielder).twice
    expect(Yielder.blocks).to eq [:foo, :bar]
  end
end
```

rspec results...

```
       expected: [:foo, :bar]
            got: [:foo, :bar, :foo, :bar]
```

am i using this incorrectly?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/yielding) this is the expected behavior.

Comment: using the same syntax with `and_return`, the behavior is different.  i would like to test `and_yield` the same way.

Comment: I suspect that what you want is actually not supported :-( my answer assumed that passing a block would work, but actually the block is run in the code, and its result is ignored (!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested, `and_yield` doesn't work the same way `and_return` does. But if you want that kind of behavior, you could do the following:

```ruby
describe Yielder do
  it 'should yield twice' do
    values = [:foo, :bar]
    allow(Yielder).to receive(:yielder) do |&block|
      block.call(values.shift)
    end

    2.times do
      Yielder.yielder do |y|
        Yielder.blocks = y
      end
    end

    expect(Yielder).to have_received(:yielder).twice
    expect(Yielder.blocks).to eq [:foo, :bar]
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you can do this with `expect()` as well, but you'll need to use `twice`, `exactly(3).times`, etc.